# When ajaxVar initialized in CActiveForm

Tags: php, yii

About `CActiveForm` in document is:(clientOptions section)

> ajaxVar: string, the name of the parameter indicating the request is an AJAX request. When the AJAX validation is triggered, a parameter named as this property will be sent together with the other form data to the server. The parameter value is the form ID. The server side can then detect who triggers the AJAX validation and react accordingly. Defaults to 'ajax'.

Now take a look in my example:
Summary: i have a form with two fields `mail` and `newEmail`, i submitted form via `ajaxSubmitButton`(if you need form code tell me put it). In following i get `var_dump($_POST)` content in two state:

**First:** Following var_dump($_POST) is for when a field(newEmail) is left empty:

```
array
'User' =>
    array
    'email' => string 'user@gmail.com' (length=14)
    'newEmail' => string '' (length=0)
```

**Second:** Following var_dump($_POST) is for when all the fields are filled:

```
array
'User' =>
    array
    'email' => string 'user@gmail.com' (length=14)
    'newEmail' => string 'admin@gmail.net' (length=19)
'ajax' => string 'email-form' (length=10)
'yt0' => string 'update' (length=18)
```

As you see only when all fields are filled the `ajaxVar(ajax)` exist in `$_POST`. When `ajaxVar(ajax)` initialized in CActiveForm?

---

## Edit

**email-form:**

```
<?php
<div class="form">
    <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array(
            'id'=>'email-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            'focus'=>'input[type="email"]:first',
            )
    )); ?>

    <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->label($model,'email') ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email') ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'email') ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->label($model,'newEmail') ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'newEmail') ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'newEmail') ?>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
            <?php  echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
            'update',
            Yii::app()->createUrl('upanel/user/CEmail'),
            array(
                    'dataType'=>'json',
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'data' => "js:$('#email-form').serialize()",
                    'success'=>'function(data){
                    if(data.status=="success")
                    {
                            //alert(data.status);
                            hideFormErrors(form="#email-form");
                            callback(status=data.status);
                    }else{
                            formErrors(data,form="#email-form");
                    }
                    }',

                    'beforeSend'=>'before',
            ),
            array(
                    'id' => 'update-button'.uniqid(),
                    'class'=>'submit-button'
            )
            );
            ?>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget() ?>
</div> 
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model,'please solve following errors:') ?>
```

**actionCEmail:**

```
public function  actionCEmail()
{
    /*ob_start();
    var_dump($_POST);
    $log=ob_get_contents();
    $fp = fopen('data.html', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $log);
    fclose($fp);
    Yii::app()->end();*/ //This block active whenever i want see the $_POST content

    $model = $this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $model->scenario = 'CEmail';
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model,'email-form');

    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        $this->renderPartial('_cemail',array('model'=>$model),false,true);
    else
        $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model,'form'=>'_cemail'));
}

protected function performAjaxValidation($model,$form)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']===$form)
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ajaxVar
```

initialized onsubmit if `'validateOnSubmit'=>true,`. Try to use `validateOnChange=>true` and show your cactiveform code when init it.

And really stop invent "a bycicle". 
Try to read http://learnyii.blogspot.com/2010/12/yii.html if you didnt understand my code in previous question.
I showed you working code of ajax validation which i use on working project. And with that method your `$_POST` will update on change of all fields with JSON object wich will contain errors for form.

Stop flooding community. Regards.

Comment: **@ineersa** I understand your answer on other question, this is other question, and your answer is very useful and i understand what when **ajaxVAr** initialized. 
**Now i understand what's my main problem:** `newEamil` field as default is empty and when submitting the form without change on this field **ajaxVar** don't initialized even if `validateOnChange=>true` is set. This problem can be solved? 
The role is: `array('email,newEmail','required', 'on'=>'CEmail', 'message'=>$required_msg),`.

Comment: Try to make active form `$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'user-form',
 'enableClientValidation'=>true,
 'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
 'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
 ),` If this doesnt help try to use `$this->performAjaxValidation($model);` in your controller. This function code something like this: `protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
 {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='user-form')
        {
                echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                Yii::app()->end();
        }
 }`

Comment: if that wont help try to read my answer 1 more time. That validation works perfectly and do exactly what you need. Also try to read this thread http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/37075-form-validation-with-ajaxsubmitbutton/ . I think its exactly what you need.

Comment: Don't work. if `newEmail` remained empty(even if fill and again empty it) then we will send the form **ajaxVar** don't initialized.

Comment: ajaxVar: string, the name of the parameter indicating the request is an AJAX request. When the AJAX validation is triggered, a parameter named as this property will be sent together with the other form data to the server. The parameter value is the form ID. The server side can then detect who triggers the AJAX validation and react accordingly. Defaults to 'ajax'.

Comment: ajaxVar is an id of your form so you can know wich 1 trigger ajax request if you have multi form action. You need ajax validation instead.

Comment: **@anyone** I very tried and noticed **ajaxVar** don't initialized when sending form via submission action(submitting form with click on **ajaxSubmitButton**). [Github Issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2381)

Comment: Write please what you trying to do with this form / action. I will try to help you tommorrow

Comment: **@ineersa** It's simple, i want whenever i clicked on **ajaxSubmtiButton** to submitting the form `$_POST` will have a content like this: 


``array
  'User' => 
    array
      'email' => string 'xxx@xxx.xxx' (length=11)
      'newEmail' => string 'yyy@yyy.yyy' (length=11)
  'ajax' => string 'email-form' (length=10)
  'yt0' => string 'update' (length=6)``



Currently the `ajax` variable with `email-form` value don't exist.

Comment: **@anyone** [CActiveForm: ajaxVar don't initialized when submitting form](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2381) tagged as Bug.

Answer (score 1):

In your action:

```
    public function  actionCEmail()
    {
        $model = $this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
        $model->scenario = 'CEmail';
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            {
                $error = CActiveForm::validate($model);
                if($error!='[]')
                                {
                                    echo $error;
                    Yii::app()->end();
                }
            }

        if(isset($_POST['CEmailForm']))
              {
               //put form name in POST above 
               //do whatever you need with model here
               //save / edit etc.
               //in the end
               echo CJSON::encode(array(
                                  'status'=>'success',
                                  )); 
           Yii::app()->end();
               }
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) //check renders 
            $this->renderPartial('_cemail',array('model'=>$model),false,true);
        else
            $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model,'form'=>'_cemail'));
    }
```

In your view submit button:

```
 <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton ("Save", Yii::app()->request->url, array (
            'dataType' => 'json', 
            'type'=>'post',
            'success' =>
            'js:function (data) {


              if(data.status=="success"){
                            //do whatever you need on success
                            //show flash/notification 
                          };

                                      }
              else {//show errors here
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        $("#YourFormIDhere #"+key+"_em_").text(val);
                $("#YourFormIDhere #"+key+"_em_").css(\'display\',\'block\');           
                                });
                        //can show error summarry here or custom notifications      
                    };

              }',
        ), array (
        'id' => 'yourbuttonid_submit_'.rand(1,255), // Need a unique id or they start to conflict with more than one load.
        ));?>
```

Try to do like this. It works. Keep it simple. You lost 2? days to validation of 2 fields.
I just made this on my changepassword form. It took me 5 minutes.
My post when trying to save with default empty field:

```
{"UserChangePassword_verifyPassword":["Required field","Retype Password is incorrect."]}
```

Make like this and dont loose time. Regards.

Comment: I had no problem with get form errors, i was just wonder why `ajaxVar` on submission action don't initialized, as the document points out, and as i discussed on Github: `string, the name of the parameter indicating the request is an AJAX request. When the AJAX validation is triggered, . . .`
however thanks for help.

Comment: I just tested. With that code provided above my POST for changepassword form contains of: `UserChangePassword[passwo... admin
UserChangePassword[verify... admin
ajax changepassword-form
yt0 Save`. So i dont understand your problem. ajaxVar works like it must. Anyway good luck with that issue.

Comment: You've been the `Github` issue? If take a look [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2381#issuecomment-16851206) i have fully explained.

Comment: Yes i saw it. With code exactly as above ajaxvar init for me as it intended.

Comment: **@ineersa,** Thanks for your effort for solving my problem, [The last result](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2381#issuecomment-16872798) and it's my answer. **Best Regard**